# Trying to catch exception and redirect back with parameters

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, parameters, exception

I'm working in laravel btw.

In a controller, I have some logic in a try/catch.  The logic is for looking up users by ID.  If a bad ID is searched, I want to catch and refresh the page with an error message like "That user ID does not exist".

I'm aware of three methods that I can use which are: `back()`, `Redirect::to('users')`, and `redirect()->route('users')`.

Firstly, which should I use?

Secondly, I've tried each and I get error messages or not the behavior I want.

### Error Messages for Each

#### `back()`

I don't see anything.  I redirect to the same page just fine. But the data I pass using `back()->withInput(['error' => $error])` doesn't show up on the page.  I have `{{isset($error) ? $error : ''}}` in my template waiting for an $error variable to be set. Is there a different way to do this? Better way?

#### `redirect()->to('users')`

This acts similarly to back() in that it will redirect me just fine but still I can't seem to pass data to the page.

#### `redirect()->route('users')`

This acts similarly to back() in that it will redirect me just fine but still I can't seem to pass data to the page.

I imagine this is a simple problem.  I'm just new to php and laravel and could use a little direction.

THANKS!

Comment: if my answer helped you, please choose it as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use input validation as bellow

```
'id' => 'exists:users,id'
```

Then you can do

```
return redirect('users')->withError($validator)
```

In the login form you can display the email not found message by

```
$errors->first('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any method you want, I'd recommend to use `back()`.

To pass error message, I'm using:

```
Session::flash('error', 'Wrong ID')
```

In a `Blade` template, I'm using this:

```
@if (Session::has('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-warning" align="center">{{ Session::get('error') }}</div>
@endif
```

Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect()->route('users')->with('error', "I have a error");

Session::get('error')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Format all the code you post using the `{}` button from the editor's toolbar. Write a short explanation of why the code you suggest works, how it works, why the code in the question does not work and/or other information you thing is appropriate for the question in case or you think it could help the question poster. This way your answers help the other and they have many chances to get up-voted. As it looks now, this answer is flagged for low quality and it will be most probably deleted soon.